# What difference in ./ ../ /

Tags: php, html

I searched around but didn't get satisfactory answer.

In directory structure i want to know what is the use of `./`
It doesn't impact if I use this in src.

Please let us know difference in `./` `../` and `/`

Comment: Is this about a directory structure (in which file system?) or about URLs? How does this relate to PHP or HTML specifically?

Answer (score 11):

`./` is the current directory.

`../` is the parent directory of current directory.

`/` is the root directory of the system.

Answer (score 3):

They work like this:

- `./` — the current directory
- `../` — the parent directory of the current directory
- `/` — the root directory of the file system

Comment: almost the same answer .. :)

Comment: @xdazz - Great minds and all that... :) Your answer popped up on my screen just as I was posting mine. +1 to the faster typist.

Answer (score 2):

./ is the current directory.

../ is the parent directory of current directory.

/ is the root directory of the system.

You can also use `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` to get the path.

For more details look at this [constants predefined](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 1):

> **./** means the current directory
>
> **../** means the parent of the current directory, not the root directory
>
> **/** is the root directory

Explanation

> myfile.text is in the **current directory**, as is **./myfile.text**
>
> **../myfile.text** is one level above you and **/myfile.text** lives in your
> **root directory.**

Answer (score 1):

If this is about URLs, as it seems – the HTML attribute `src` takes a URL value – then it really has nothing to with directories. Interpretation of relative URLs takes place as string manipulation, without any reference to directories or files. (A *resolved* URL, absolute URL, may then be interpreted in a manner that maps things to a file system, but that is a different issue.)

At the start of a URL,

`./` has no effect (it is removed in interpreting a relative URL)

`../` causes the last part of the base URL, back to its last `/` in it, to be removed before using it as a prefix

`/` causes the URL to be prefixed by the protocol and server part of the current base URL

Thus, assuming a base URL of `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/zap`,

`./test.html` resolves to the same as `test.html`, namely `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/test.html`

`../test.html` resolves to `http://www.example.com/foo/test.html`

`/test.html` resolves to `http://www.example.com/test.html`

Reference: [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66).

If it happens that the absolute URLs are then interpreted, by the server running at www.example.com, in a simplistic (and common) manner by mapping them to a file system, then `./` maps to the same directory as the base URL, `../` maps to its parent directory, and `/` maps to the server root.