# getting php working directory path

Tags: php

My file structure is here

```
-www
  -myAppDirectory
     -init
        -connect.php
     -products
        -api.php
```

*products/api.php* file will include the *init/connect.php* file like following.

```
<?php
 include_once("./connect.php");
```

users can call api.php from browser.

but it gives warning

```
Warning: include_once(./connect.php): failed to open stream
```

I try using this:

```
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/connect.php");
```

but it gives warning,

```
Warning: include_once(D:\init\www/connect.php): failed to open stream
```

Answer (score 2):

Using absolute path is always good (*clean and solid*).

```
include_once(__DIR__ . "/../init/connect.php");
```

Comment: what means "/../" in path?

Comment: "/../" go to parent directory.

Comment: @bookmarker See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249525/what-difference-in/21249534#21249534

Comment: I read link thanks but clear something, is root directory www, and is current directory myAppDirectory? or is current directory requested file directory?

Answer (score 1):

try `../` for out the **products** dir then add path connect.php

```
include_once("../init/connect.php");
```

you can also use (not tested) `./` for root

```
include_once("./init/connect.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
include_once("./connect.php");
```

will check for a file outside the parent directory ie., outside *products* and there is no any file *connect.php* outside it. You have to use

```
include_once("../init/connect.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to give more detailed answer.

For starters I'd like to mention what is `__DIR__` it's one of [PHP: Magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

It contains the path of the directory in which your current script is executed.
In your case, something similar to: `D:\init\www\myAppDirectory\products` without ending slash (on windows)/back-slash (linux, etc.)

So for example `__FILE__` would give you `D:\init\www\myAppDirectory\products\api.php`

Now if you want to include file from relatively closer directory, I'd prefer to use:

```
include_once("../init/connect.php");
```

(maybe not required but) Also it's good practice to use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

```
include_once(".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "init". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."connect.php");
```

You can also use `dirname($path)` function:

```
$myAppDir = dirname(__DIR__); // D:\init\www\myAppDirectory
include $myAppDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "init". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."connect.php"
```

Also `include` can be faster than `include_once` because the last one have to check first over the included files.

[Why is require_once so bad to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186338/why-is-require-once-so-bad-to-use)